# I have Three Lists with user inputs how to create a table flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable, flutter-layout

Lists with user inputs

```
List1 =[1,2,3,.....];
List2 =[0.1,0.2,0.3,.....];
List3 =[0.5,0.10,6.0,....];
```

How Can I Create a table Like following image Please help Me I am stuck

**Final Out Example Image**
[image: Final Out Example Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a List of Lists. You could do something like this:

```
List<List<dynamic>> listMap = [];

listMap.add(List1);
listMap.add(List2);
listMap.add(List3);
```

Note I put dynamic because I don't know what types of variables you want.

Comment: how to represent into a table

Comment: what do you mean by represent into a table? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: please check attached image

Comment: Final Out Example Image Attached with Question

Comment: you want to create a visual table?

Comment: Data not retrieve into a sequence

Comment: I want to Retrieve data into table like image example

Comment: the solution I gave you does that. You will have a List called listMap where inside it has 3 lists. For example, to get into the first element of the first list, you could do `data = listMap[0][0];`

Comment: But the issue is Lists of Length is not fixed

Comment: Length is from User Input

Comment: i Need This This =>>>   ListMap[0][All indexes];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239111/discussion-between-muhammad-awais-younas-and-quim).

Answer (score 1):

My Lists

```
List1 =[1,2,3,.....];
List2 =[0.1,0.2,0.3,.....];
List3 =[0.5,0.10,6.0,....];
```

Table Widget

```
Widget createTable() {
List<TableRow> rows = [];
for (int i = 0; i < xList.length; i++) {
rows.add(TableRow(children: [
Text(List1[i].toString()),
Text(List2[i].toString()),
Text(List3[i].toString()),
]));
}
return Table(children: rows);}
```